# Sagemaker : How do I set content_type in Predictor (Sagemake > 2.0)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Requesting assistance with the following error.

> An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint
> operation: Received client error (415) from model with message
> "Content-type application/octet-stream not supported. Supported
> content-type is text/csv, text/libsvm"

Here is the relevant code -

```
from sagemaker import image_uris
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator

xgboost_hyperparameters = {
        "max_depth":"5",
        "eta":"0.2",
        "gamma":"4",
        "min_child_weight":"6",
        "subsample":"0.7",
        "num_round":"50"
}

xgboost_image = image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", boto3.Session().region_name, version="1")



estimator = Estimator(image_uri = xgboost_image,
                     hyperparameters = xgboost_hyperparameters,
                     role = role,
                     instance_count=1, 
                     instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge', 
                      output_path= output_loc,
                     volume_size=5 )

from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import CSVDeserializer

train_input = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3_data = train_loc, content_type='text/csv',s3_data_type = 'S3Prefix')
valid_input = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3_data = validation_loc, content_type='text/csv',s3_data_type = 'S3Prefix')

estimator.CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/csv'
estimator.serializer = CSVSerializer()
estimator.deserializer = None

estimator.fit({'train':train_input, 'validation': valid_input})

# deploy model with data config
from sagemaker.model_monitor import DataCaptureConfig
from time import gmtime, strftime
s3_capture_upload_path = 's3://{}/{}/monitoring/datacapture'.format(bucket, prefix)
model_name = 'project3--model-' + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
endpoint_name = 'project3-endpoint'
data_capture_configuration = DataCaptureConfig(
                        enable_capture = True,
                        sampling_percentage=100,
                        destination_s3_uri=s3_capture_upload_path  )

deploy = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1,
                          instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge'    ,
                          data_capture_config=data_capture_configuration,
                          model_name=model_name,
                          endpoint_name = endpoint_name
                         )
```

Then I face the error in the *Predictor*

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor

predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        print(row)
        payload = row.rstrip('\n')
        response = predictor.predict(data=payload[2:])
        sleep(0.5)
print('done!')
```

I looked at these links but haven't found an answer

1. https://github.com/aws-samples/reinvent2019-aim362-sagemaker-debugger-model-monitor/blob/master/02_deploy_and_monitor/deploy_and_monitor.ipynb
2. [How can I specify content_type in a training job of XGBoost from Sagemaker in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908395/how-can-i-specify-content-type-in-a-training-job-of-xgboost-from-sagemaker-in-py)
3. https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/729

Answer (score 6):

As seen [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.15.2/api/inference/predictors.html#sagemaker.predictor.Predictor.predict), predict()'s initial_args is "Default arguments for boto3 [invoke_endpoint](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint) call.

For me, this worked:

```
predictor.predict(review_input, initial_args={'ContentType': 'text/plain'})
```

Comment: Thanks initial_args={'ContentType': 'text/csv'}. Works awesome.

Answer (score 4):

First, please make sure which SDK version you are using. AWS made breaking changes between 1.x and 2.x. Even worse, the sagemaker SDK on notebook instance can be different from that in the sagemaker studio depending on the regions.

Please see [How to use Serializer and Deserializer in Sagemaker 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63568274/how-to-use-serializer-and-deserializer-in-sagemaker-2) as well as AWS changed serialize/deserialize stuff.

- [Predictors](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictors.html)

> Behavior for serialization of input data and deserialization of result data can be configured through **initializer arguments**.

- [class sagemaker.serializers.CSVSerializer(content_type='text/csv')](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/serializers.html#sagemaker.serializers.CSVSerializer)

Please try:

```
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer()
```

Or by setting None to the serializer, you can have full control over serialize/deserialize in your code.

```
predictor.serializer=None
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the reference API for predictor [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.15.2/api/inference/predictors.html#sagemaker.predictor.Predictor.predict) with `initial_args`

> predictor.predict(review_input, initial_args={'ContentType':
> 'text/csv'})

Comment: how would you tell the endpoint to give *back* the same content type as the input content type? It seems to default to giving back the response predictions as json format (which casues an issue when setting up model monitor later; the input and output types of the endpoint must be the same)