# How do I set 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ACCEPT' in Predictor (Sagemaker > 2.0)?

Tags: python, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

Here is the relevant code

```
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[boto3.Session().region_name],
                                         role,
                                         train_instance_count=1,
                                         train_instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                                         output_path=s3_model_output_location,
                                         sagemaker_session=sess,
                                         base_job_name = 'xgboost-baterias-v1')


estimator.set_hyperparameters(max_depth=5,
                             objective="multi:softmax",
                             num_class=3,
                             num_round=50,
                             early_stopping_rounds=10)


training_input_config=sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_data=s3_training_file_location,content_type="csv")
validation_input_config=sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_data=s3_validation_file_location,content_type="csv")

estimator.fit({'train':training_input_config, 'validation': validation_input_config})

predictor = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                            instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                            endpoint_name = 'xgboost-baterias-v1')

from sagemaker.predictor import CSVSerializer, JSONDeserializer, CSVDeserializer, Predictor


predictor.CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/csv'
predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer
predictor.deserializer = None
```

> Here comes the error using predictor

```
predictor.predict([[13.5,70.17,13.06,9.69]])
```

> The testing file is a .csv file composed by 5 columns each one of them representing a variable

> I found this link but I didn't find the answer
> < [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202873/sagemaker-how-do-i-set-content-type-in-predictor-sagemake-2-0>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202873/sagemaker-how-do-i-set-content-type-in-predictor-sagemake-2-0%3E)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this in one of the two ways -

1. Use a custom Serializer/Deserializer as shown below -

> ```
> from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer
> from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer
>
>
> class FMSerializer(JSONSerializer):
>     def serialize(self, data):
>         js = {'instances': []}
>         for row in data:
>             js['instances'].append({'features': row.tolist()})
>         return json.dumps(js)
>
>
> predictor = estimator.deploy(
>     initial_instance_count=1,
>     instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
>     serializer=FMSerializer(),
>     deserializer=JSONDeserializer()
> )
> ```

2. Use one of the DeSerializers listed [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/deserializers.html).